# Applying bootstrap styles to django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to use bootstrap to get a decent website design, unfortunately I don't know how style the form fields. I am talking about this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.title.label }}
  {{ form.title }}
</form>
```

How is one supposed to design this?? I tried this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-control">
    {{ form.title.label }}
    {{ form.title }}
  </div>
</form>
```

This obviously didn't gave me the wanted results.

How can I apply bootstrap styles to django forms?

Comment: django-bootstrap3 will really make your life easier. https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3

Comment: @Quaker I will check that out, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you prefer not to use 3rd party tools then essentially you need to add attributes to your classes, I prefer to do this by having a base class that my model forms inherit from

```
class BootstrapModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BootstrapModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
```

Can easily be adjusted... but as you see all my field widgets get the form-control css class applied

You can extend this for specific fields if you wish, here's an example of an inherited form having an attribute applied

```
class MyForm(BootstrapModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Enter a name'})
```

Comment: Well this is really cool! I don't like using 3 party tools but sticking more to the framework! I love it, thank you

Comment: @FooBar - No worries, enjoy! :)

Comment: this class would go into my forms.py file? noob question, i know. i just started learning django so i'm not 100% sure...

Comment: @Jeannie yea you can put it anywhere that makes sense really. You can import it throughout your projects as required