# Customize Django Form Style

Tags: css, django, django-forms

how can i customize Django forms and set class for them ? for example i have a text box with bootstrap class and custom font :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control myfont" value="{{ model1.field1 }}"/>
```

but original form field " **{{ form1.form_field1 }}** " is a simple textbox with no style . i try to use this code :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control myfont" value="{{ form1.form_field1 }}"/>
```

this code didn't work . do you have suggestions ??

[image]

Comment: {{ form1.form_field1 }} renders an entire form field to the page. {{ form1.form_field1.value }} is what will render the value of that field to the page. Injecting the value of the form.form_field1 into a piece of html you wrote is not a good idea though, since it won't handle the escaping of the string properly. You will lose a lot of django goodness.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying bootstrap styles to django forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986780/applying-bootstrap-styles-to-django-forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add extra attributes to widgets in form's `__init__` method. If you many such forms, then you can have one super class form:

```
class BootstrapForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BootstrapForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in self.fields:
            field = self.fields.get(field_name)
            if field:
                field.widget.attrs.update({
                    'class': "form-control myfont"
                })
```

And then have your other forms extend this one.

Comment: @ArashHatami Doesn't work in the sense? Can you post your template?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to inject extra attributes with the least resistance you can use django-tweaks.

## Installation

```
 $ pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

Then add ‘widget_tweaks’ to INSTALLED_APPS.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks

### template.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% render_field form1.form_field1 class="form-control myfont" %}
```

Comment: i have error : **"'widget_tweaks' is not a valid tag library"**

Comment: Read the docs on how to install django-tweaks, it is a third party app so you will have to pip install, and add it to your settings.py.