# Is it neccessary to use a django package to have my web app styled with bootstrap?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I was thinking of just importing the static files and add the classes that I need. But I see that there are several django packages to support bootstrap 3. Why do I need one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying bootstrap styles to django forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986780/applying-bootstrap-styles-to-django-forms)

Comment: My answer in that duplicate explains how you could do it without third party apps...

Comment: @Sayse that question is not exactly a duplicate. I'm trying to understand the motivation of having the plugins and why I simply can't just import the statics. Nevertheless I have found your answer useful.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary. These packages are to make the things easier for the developer. But if you're familiar with bootstrap, you can use it directly. Even in the renowned [`cookiecutter-django`](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/templates/base.html) project template,  bootstrap it's used directly.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not. You only need bootstrap's css and js files. But, in this approach, you should use them manually in your template files and handle classes and necessary files by yourself. For example for buttons, you should add `btn btn-default` classes to your buttons:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
```

But, by using Django-Bootstrap3, you can use something like this:

```
{% buttons submit='OK' reset="Cancel" %}{% endbuttons %}
```

And it generates two bootstrap style button. That's it!
Also, some packages allows you to use bootstrap components on the forms instead of template files and they handle necessary classes for elements.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to understand the motivation of having the plugins and why I simply can't just import the statics

As with all plugins/third party apps, they're goal is to make things easier, but as I hope you've seen from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32986885/1324033), its really not difficult at all and I'd just go for it and do it yourself (as I do).

The only possible benefit from the libraries I've seen is they all work off template tags in an effort to make your code DRYer by having a central place where css attributes are added. Even this I find questionable if it achieves it over other methods and I wonder if its even less performant as it leaves you with even more template rendering.

Tl;dr: They try to make your life easier but really you could just import them.