# Django fields assign to html fields

Tags: django, django-forms

How to assign Django fields to html fields. Without adding `{{form}}` in html?

The actual problem that I want my fields to look like this:

[image: Bootstrap group input]

But if I use this `{{form}}`, what I can get is

[image: General bootstrap input]

I've created a custom form, can I assign my input fields from HTML to form class fields in Django?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying bootstrap styles to django forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986780/applying-bootstrap-styles-to-django-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved this problem (it was very simple)

1. I installed [django-widget-tweaks 1.4.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks)

   *pip install django-widget-tweaks*
2. My code started to look like this

```html
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
  {{ form.username | add_class:'form-control' | attr:"placeholder:Username"}}
</div>
```

**Note:** form.username - *username* is name of your field in forms.py

Answer (score 0):

simple answer You can have your own form not use `{{ form }}` just give the `input` tag.

```
<input type="text" name="<your name">
```

Please note given `name` must match the your database field.

yes of course you can create the custom form

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        widgets = {
            'your_field': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'yourFieldClass'}),
        }
```