# Is there a way to link input fields from HTML to the ACTUAL form fields used in DJANGO

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

Right now I'm stuck between two things: Either I have a login form that works but isn't exactly what you call visually appealing and one that looks flawless but doesn't do anything. (I know quite the situation)

[image: If you look at this image right here you'll know exactly what I'm talking about:]

As shown the one up top is clearly quite the looker (sarcasm*), but I want the hideous one at the bottom to work.

For the for up top, I just used `{{ form }}` tag and have at one point my code looked like this:

```
<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.username.label_tag }}
    {{ form.username }}
    {{ form.password.label_tag }}
    {{ form.password }}

   <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block' value='{{ title }}' />
</form>
```

But again this doesn't give me the look I want. As of right now, to get the non-functional (but pretty) form look at the bottom I'm using the code for the [bootstrap template signin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/) (signin.css included in my base template). This is what my form.html looks like right now:

```
{% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
        <form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data' class="form-signin">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form}}
            <h2 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please Sign In</h2>
            <input type="username" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input type='submit' class='"btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block' value='{{ title }}' />
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have seen another StackOverflow post [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496439/django-fields-assign-to-html-fields) and tried installing `django-widget-tweaks` but since I'm using cloud9-ide it didn't work

[image: cloud9-ide it didn't work]

So please if there's a way where I could either somehow implement the form tags in my Html or successfully download django-tweaks, please let me know and I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean `link`? you want to use your form in html for your own way?

Comment: Thanks @seuling for your response and I'm sorry I didn't make that clear the first time. What I meant to say was that I wanted to make the html input fields (pretty ones) be the functional ones in terms of connect to my database and signing in like my `/admin/` page would. Using the `{{ form }}` works but as you can see it doesn't look like the bootstrap one on the bottom.

Comment: can you upload the result of using `{{ form }}`? You can see in browser. (i.e. dev tools)

Comment: I think it's not working well because it doesn't have bootstrap class, right? Then you just can add class to your form

Answer (score 0):

You need `name` attributes in your html inputs if you want the browser to send data fur them. This is nothing to do with Django.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for your feedback, I really appreciate it. However can you be more clear on what I put exactly in those `name=""` tags for the input fields? Do I put the `{{ form.username }}` and `{{ form.password}}` tags? Thanks again

Comment: No. If you want to use straight HTML, you need `<input type='whatever'.... name='username'>` etc.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `action = ''` and try again:

```
<form method='post'>{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.username.label_tag }}
    {{ form.username }}
    {{ form.password.label_tag }}
    {{ form.password }}

   <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block' value='{{ title }}' />
</form>
```

Or install django-tweaks in a virtual environment

```
pip install pipenv --user
cd
. .bashrc
cd workspace/mysite
pipenv --three
pipenv shell
pipenv install django django-widget-tweaks
python manage.py runserver
```

Also suggest you to upgrade python to version 3.6