# How can I add class into all fields of my form?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

How can I add class `form-control` into all fields of my form?

```
class AddOfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddOfferForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
```

Comment: Are you using `Bootstrap 3` and wants to have `form-control` class added using `crispy-forms`?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying bootstrap styles to django forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986780/applying-bootstrap-styles-to-django-forms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [template pack](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#template-packs) in crispy forms to bootstrap3 in your settings file:

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
```

And, this will automatically add `form-control` class to each input control in the form.

Comment: Thank you! I had CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap' :)