# Styling a generic.edit.CreateView Form in Django Using Bootstrap

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following view in my Django app:

```
class TodoCreateView(generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = Todo
    fields = ['todo_name','todo_description']
    template_name = 'list/todo-create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list:index')
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        form.instance.created_date = datetime.now()
        return super(EntryCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

This view corresponds to the following template:

```
{% extends 'list/base.html' %}

{# Load the tag library #}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}


{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Todo:</h1>
<div>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Obviously, Django composes and outputs the form based on the fields indicated in the View. However, it seems to leave no chance to style the form fields with CSS. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide the `get_form_class` function of the view and set that to a modelform_factory with a baseclass that provides bootstrap styling - See [Applying bootstrap styles to django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986780/applying-bootstrap-styles-to-django-forms/32986885#32986885) for a simple example of this.

```
class TodoCreateView(generic.edit.CreateView):
     def get_form_class(self):
          return modelform_factory(self.model, form=MyBaseForm, fields=self.fields)
```

Otherwise, its much easier to create a form yourself and then set that to `form_class`

```
class TodoForm(MyBaseForm):
    pass

form_class = TodoForm
```

Comment: Is it then possible to style the Django form I create?

Comment: @MadPhysicist - See the linked question