# How to make my forms work in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I just created a Bootstrap 3 website with Django. My website has 4 different pop-up modals in the following order:  1. Uploading your display image, 2. adding basic information, 3. choosing login credentials and 4. adding their personal biography.

These 4 modals all contain their own html form, so I have 4 different forms for the user to register their account. My question is how do I link all 4 forms together so I can pass the information to my Django server and generate the user in my database?

I've seen videos of people generating their forms through a Forms.py file, but I can't do it that way because I already have my forms. If I did not spend my time designing the frond end I would just delete the forms and generate them again through a Forms.py file, but I did.

Anyone who can help me out? I'm quite new to Django.

Comment: What do you mean you 'already have my forms'? You'll need to create django forms then integrate your markup with them. You should probably take a look at this; https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3

Comment: I already have them designed with css. It'll take too much time to recreate and redesign them.

Comment: You don't need to redesign them. You can use your existing markup with the form in django. Post some example markup & whatever you've tried to do with django forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying bootstrap styles to django forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986780/applying-bootstrap-styles-to-django-forms)

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the concept of forms in django.
They're designed and created to validate user input before saving to database, and generating html from form classes is just additional feature, you mustn't use it.

To make your bootstrapped forms work, you must create django form with all the fields(all fields from your 4 forms), and then:

```
`............................
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
 .....................`
```

And override `form.save` with user-creating functionality.

Comment: ..Why shouldn't you use Django's template renderer to render the forms for you?..

Comment: I didn't say you shouldn't, i said that you **mustn't**. It's **not required** for forms to work.

Comment: Ok then, why *mustn't* you? One of the big advantages of using forms is that you don't have to worry about their maintenance

Comment: Question author wanted to work with already generated forms in bootstrap, and to generate not-straightforward forms via django requires knowledge/practice with widgets, which isn't required for forms to be used for validation.