# Beautify django form html

Tags: html, django, django-forms

The `form.as_ul` shortcut works completely fine but the html isn't formatted. The only solution I found was to include a middleware which beautifies the **complete** html but I only want to do that for the form part. Is there a other way than write my own form template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying bootstrap styles to django forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986780/applying-bootstrap-styles-to-django-forms)

Comment: When you say "beautify", do you mean the formatting of the code itself (as opposed to the way it's styled for the end user to see)? If so, consider just not caring. In most cases that is entirely unimportant. If you do care about how your code is laid out you can always [render fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) but, again, it's probably not worth it.

Comment: @Chris your comment answers my question. Thank you! Should I now write an answer and repeat what you said?

Comment: @R3turnz, which part of it solved your problem? The part about manually rendering fields?

Comment: @Chris that readability for the end user is not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the formatting of the HTML code itself, consider not worrying about it.

In most cases the formatting of your HTML code is unimportant. It gets consumed by a browser and rendered for users. It is that rendered output that is important.

(Just for fun, load up your local Google search page and have a look at its source. It's definitely not optimized for people to read.)

In case you *do* want to format your HTML in a particular way you can always [render fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).